# some questions about xodus

Tags: xodus, xodus-dnq

yo! i have some questions about xodus.

1. if i get something from entity using getProperty, do i take it from memory or read from database?
   if from database, is there a built-in ability to turn on some cache system?
2. can i work directly on an entity as in normal data classes? should i cover them with some extra intermediate layer?
3. why youtrack need schema-less database?
4. why xodus out of the box supports only chacha20 and salsa20 and not, for example, aes which is used practically everywhere and recognized as a standard?
5. is it a good idea to use xodus in a mail server?

Answer (score 2):

1. There are different caches that Xodus can use while getting a property value.
2. Entity methods require an implicit transaction in current thread.
3. Schema-less database is much more suitable for implementation of YouTrack's data model, e.g. custom fields.
4. AES is a block cipher, whereas Xodus uses stream ciphers which tend to be faster. There are no indications that ChaCha20 is less secure than AES, and ChaCha20 is always faster than AES on systems where the CPU does not feature AES acceleration.